# Java, Selenium стираются русские буквы при заполнении поля

Tags: java, selenium, chromedriver

Прошу помощи с полем ввода (картинки поля по ссылкам)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Принимает значения в формате: "II-ЛВ 123123"

**Проблема заключается в том, что когда начинаю вводить цифры или перехожу к заполнению другого поля, русские символы затираются.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ввожу руками, то русские буквы остаются.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поле:

`<input data-v-df8e4b70="" type="text" inputmode="text" name="birthCertificate" id="birthCertificate" data-at-locator="birthCertificate" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off" class="text-input__input">`

`css = "input[id='birthCertificate']")`

Это я пробовала:

- birthCertificateField.sendKeys("II-ЛВ 123123");
- birthCertificateField.type("II-ЛВ 123123");
- Вводила с паузами посимвольно
- В разной очередности.
- Использовала CTRL+V(локально помогло, но удаленно на тачках падает)
- В другое поле мое значение заполняется без потерь

Особенность - поле не теряет символы, если заполняется английскими буквами:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45
Заранее спасибо за советы

Answer (score 0):

sendKeys, похоже, пытается подражать человеку и отправляет не текст, а нажатия клавишь на клавиатуре. У вс тандартно стоит, скорее всего, английский, на нем кирилицы нет, вот оно их и не печатает
Попробуйте поменять язык
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=ru-RU")

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, не помогло.